# JAAS subject propagation from Servelet container to OSGI

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am using geronimo 3.0 AS. I have OSGI bundles as web services and webapp as frontend. I am using JAAS and i want to know how to get the authenticated username(Subject) in my osgi bundles.Currently, i can get the username from the webapp using request.getRemoteUser() but it returns null in my OSGI bundles.